# React - sort messages in monthly sections

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components

I am trying to group a list of messages in monthly sections. Every time the month changes I want to add a header `<h2>Previous Month</h2>` and then display all the messages from that month.

Here is my attempt:

MessageList.js

```
import React from "react"

export default class MessageList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  render() {

      var currentDate = new Date()
      var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()
      var timeline=""

      var mssgTypeList = {
        "this_month" : [],
        "last_month" : [],
        "previous_month" : []
       }

       this.props.messages.forEach(function(message,index){
          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10)
          var time = message.date.slice(12)

          var messageDate = new Date(date)
          var messageMonth = messageDate.getMonth()

          if(currentMonth == messageMonth) {
            timeline == 'this_month'
          } else if(currentMonth == messageMonth + 1){
            timeline = 'last_month'
          } else if(currentMonth == messageMonth + 2) {
            timeline = 'previous_month'
          }

          mssgTypeList[timeline].push(message);

       });

       const ThisMonthMessageList = mssgTypeList["this_month"].map((message) => {
          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
          var time = message.date.slice(12);

            return (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
                  Date: {date} <br></br>
                  Time: {time} <br></br>
                  Body: {message.body}
                </li>
            )
       });

       const LastMonthMessageList = mssgTypeList["last_month"].map((message) => {
          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
          var time = message.date.slice(12);

            return (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
                  Date: {date} <br></br>
                  Time: {time} <br></br>
                  Body: {message.body}
                </li>
            ) 
       })

      const PreviousMonthMessageList = mssgTypeList["previous_month"].map((message) => {
          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
          var time = message.date.slice(12);

            return (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
                  Date: {date} <br></br>
                  Time: {time} <br></br>
                  Body: {message.body}
                </li>
            ) 
      })

      return (
          <div id="messageList">

            <h2>This Month</h2>
            <ul className="list-group this-month-group">
              {ThisMonthMessageList}
            </ul>

            <h2>Last Month</h2>
            <ul className="list-group last-month-group">
              {LastMonthMessageList}
            </ul>

            <h2>Previous Month</h2>
            <ul className="list-group previous-month-group">
              {PreviousMonthMessageList}
            </ul>
          </div>
         )
       }
```

The problem here is that this only generates a limited number of monthly sections; Basically sections that I hardcoded in `mssgTypeList`. It does not dynamically create a new section whenever the month changes.

How do I dynamically generate a new section every time the month changes?

Or is there an alternative way to sort messages in monthly sections? Maybe create additional components?

Comment: `mssgTypeList[message.date.substring(0, 5)].push(message);` and if your messages are sorted by date, you can just compare month of current message with previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably a better idea to put all the logic that depends in the props in the `componentWillReceiveProps` Method and the same should be present in the `componentDidMount` function since `componentWillReceiveProps` is not being called the initial time. Also having all this logic in the render is expensive since render is called any state change.

Dynamic rendering can be achieved in the following manner, however it would be better if you include the month with the year as a key.

```js
export default class MessageList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      msgTypeList : {
       }
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      var currentDate = new Date()
      var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()
      var messageTypeList = {}
       this.props.messages.forEach((message, index) => {
          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10)
          var messageDate = new Date(date)
          var messageMonth = messageDate.getMonth();
          messageTypeList[messageMonth].push(message);
       })
       this.setState({messageTypeList});
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      var currentDate = new Date()
      var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()
      var timeline=""
      var messageTypeList = {}
       nextProps.messages.forEach((message, index) => {
          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10)
          var messageDate = new Date(date)
          var messageMonth = messageDate.getMonth();
          messageTypeList[messageMonth].push(message);
       })
       this.setState({messageTypeList});
  }
  render() {

       return (

          <div id="messageList">
             {Object.keys(this.state.messageTypeList).map((key) => {
                 return (
                  <div>
                  <h2>{key}</h2>
                  <ul className="list-group">
                      {this.state.messageTypeList[key].map((message) => {
                          var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
                          var time = message.date.slice(12);

                            return (
                                <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
                                  Date: {date} <br></br>
                                  Time: {time} <br></br>
                                  Body: {message.body}
                                </li>
                            ) 
                       })}
                   </ul>
                   </div>
                   )
               })
             }
              </div>
       )


   }
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at this line {Object.keys(this.state.messageTypeList).map((key) .. And where do I put the componentDidMount function?

Comment: Updated the answer, there was a syntax error with state in the constructor

Comment: I tried that as well and I needed to wrap a <div> around the <h2> and <ul> as well. I still got that error

Comment: At this line: {Object.keys(this.state.messageTypeList).map((key)

I get this error: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

-- I assume it means my messageTypeList is null which means the componentWillReceiveProps did not work

Comment: Sorry a mistake againfrom my end, a typo in constructor state just fixed it in the answe

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Notice that `{ThisMonthMessageList}` is not hard-code but you build it. Well you can do the same thing for your entire message list. Your `render` return statement would then look something like this:

```
  return (
      <div id="messageList">
        {messageList}
      </div>
  );
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you thinking about this the right way.